# asp:button onClick='navigate + run method'

Tags: asp.net, aspbutton

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Create" OnClick="Create_Click" CssClass="FadeOutOnEdit"/>
```

This runs the Create_Click method in the aspx.cs page.(Which adds data to the DB)

I would like to run this method and also navigate to a different page when the btn is clicked.
I have been trying:

```
NavigateUrl="~/Invoices/List.aspx"
 ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx"
```

any suggestions
Thank ye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to represent the destination URL in markup, why not use Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect in the code for Create_Click?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that what you're after is callbacks, though postback would be fine here.

Here is a really good article explaining the concept and giving sample code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163941.aspx